# How to check if transaction belongs to Uniswap using etherscan api?

Tags: etherscan, uniswap

I want to check all transaction this address https://etherscan.io/tokentxns?a=0x534a0076fb7c2b1f83fa21497429ad7ad3bd7587

How can I filter Uniswap transaction using etherscan api?
I tried filter using sender address, but "Uniswap V2: DOGPORK" address and "Uniswap V2: TOADOG" address are different.

Should I collect all addresses ("Uniswap V2: ORDIB", "Uniswap V2: PLAN 4", etc) or there is another way?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

Uniswap wallets have the same contractInfo->creatorAddress

Get address info:

```
https://api.ethplorer.io/getAddressInfo/0x8d73fb6fd6ae3d235c7b84808d07315fea959539?apiKey=freekey
```

If creatorAddress == '0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d' the wallet belongs to Uniswap.